# How to add schema markup on dynamic codeigniter pages

Tags: codeigniter, schema

I want to add schema markup on dynamically created codeigniter pages. as per my understanding you can add schema to optimize SEO search results and it can be added in header file. But i have dynamically created pages which shows different category pages and i need to add scheme for all those category pages. 
Problem is how to add different schema for multiple pages if there is only one header for all pages.
Here is the view page code:

```
 <?php
$this->load->view("landing/header");
?>
<div class="container" >
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($services); $i = $i + 3) {
    ?>
        <div class="row <?= (($i != 0) && ($i != (count($services) - 1))) ? 'sm-pad-v' : '' ?>">
        <?php
        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        if (isset($services[$i + $j])) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 assignment-content">
                <h3>
                <strong>
                    <a href="<?= base_url($services[$i + $j]->seo_url) ?>"><?= $services[$i + $j]->service_name; ?> </a>
                </strong>
                </h3>
                <p>
                <?= trimText(strip_tags($services[$i + $j]->description), 150) ?>
                <a class="" href="<?= base_url($services[$i + $j]->seo_url) ?>"><span class="read-more">read more</span></a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Here is the code for schema markup:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "Programming Assignment Help",
    "alternateName" : "AJAX Programing Assignment Help",
    "url" : "https://www.assignment.com/"
    }
```

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization ",
    "url" : "https://www.Assignment.com/",
    "logo" : "https://www.assignmenthelp.com/assets/img/logo-p-lite.png ",
"contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "email" : "support@Assignment.com",
    "URL" : "https://www.Assignment.com/contact-us",
    "contactType" : "customer service"
    }]
    }
```

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "AJAX Programming Assignment Help",
        "image": "https://www.Assignment.com/uploads/1559752385394.jpg",
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.9",
        "ratingCount": "5500"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You could supply dynamic variable into that header though..

Comment: @HastaDhana but how to add dynamic variables to schema markup

Comment: @HastaDhana I have edited my question you can see markup code above

Comment: If the header is a PHP file, then you could load a variable into it as a schema value from the controller, just like loading a variable for the content of the page

Comment: @HastaDhana Thank you !! I resolved the issue by sending controller variables into schema